# Directiva ngSwitchCase con varias opciones en Angular

Tags: angular, switch, angular-directivas

Tengo un Template donde utilizo NgSwitch y tengo una condición que si se cumple, se debe ejecutar el mismo bloque.

```
Este es el ejemplo:
<div class="width-100" [ngSwitch]="identificatorString">

    ...
    
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'pesificacion'" class="body-card">
        <span class="delete-date" (click)="deleteDateSelected()">Borrar fecha seleccionada</span>
        <mat-card class="inline-calendar-card">
            <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
        </mat-card>
    </div>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'wayPay'" class="body-card">
        <span class="delete-date" (click)="deleteDateSelected()">Borrar fecha seleccionada</span>
        <mat-card class="inline-calendar-card">
            <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
        </mat-card>
    </div>

...
</div>
```

Supongo que esto está mal. Estoy repitiendo código y supongo que hay una forma más sencilla de hacerlo.

Probé haciendo esto (juntando las dos condiciones en una, pero solo muestra el que esté primero, en este caso 'pesificacion':

```
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'pesificacion' || 'wayPay'" class="body-card">
        <span class="delete-date" (click)="deleteDateSelected()">Borrar fecha seleccionada</span>
        <mat-card class="inline-calendar-card">
            <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
```

Sé como realizarlo con Javascript:

```
switch (identificatorString) {
  case 'pesificacion':
  case 'wayPay':
    ...
    break;
}
```

pero no sé como llevarlo al template.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sencilla sería precisamente agrupar en el Controller las opciones usando un switch:

```
private option: string;

...

switch (identificatorString) {
  case 'pesificacion':
  case 'wayPay':
    this.option = ...
    break;
}
```

Y así puedes usar ese valor en el template:

```
<div class="width-100" [ngSwitch]="option">
```